# Where to place files to make tham visible for Applet?

Tags: java, eclipse, applet, filenotfoundexception, appletviewer

I have a problem with Applet. First I have to pick file with data with JFileChooser. After that JTable is created. Since I run this Applet with AppletViewer from Eclipse everything is ok. But when I try to do this when I place it in HTML file I get FileNotFoundException even though I made some needed permision in .java.policy. Could you give me some tips, where should I place files general to make them visible for Applet? I mean they are in eclipse project directory and they are visible when I run Applet with AppletViever but they are not visible when I run it from HTML but they are still in project directory.

Comment: your html file is also in the same project structure ? update your question with snapshot of your project structure

Comment: my html file is in bin directory with .class files

Comment: then it must work...have you given code = "packageNames.ClassName.class" in applet tag ?

Comment: It's in default package. It's very strange issue for me...

Comment: *"I have a problem with Applet. First I have to pick file with data with JFileChooser"* Is this data supplied by you or the end user?  Is the applet digitally signed?

Comment: Data is supplied by end user. No applet isn't digitally signed.